# Emploi d'excuse : influencé par l'anglais sorry ?

Tags: usage

J'ai entendu plusieurs jeunes (collégiens, lycéens, étudiants post-bac) utiliser le mot 'excuse'. Par exemple, lors d'un match football amical un joueur a bousculé un adversaire. Le premier joueur a dit au second 'excuse' pour s'excuser. Cet usage est-il influencé par l'anglais sorry ou est-il seulement un raccourci pour la complète tournure 'excuse-moi' ? Est-il récent ? Est-il plus courant aux jeunes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non, la forme « ***Excuse !*** » n'est ni récente, ni influencée par l'anglais.

C'est un impératif assez direct, sans le pronom **moi** (sous-entendu) et uniquement employé dans un contexte relâché, effectivement comme peut l'être un match de football.

On rencontre aussi la forme avec vouvoiement « ***Excusez !*** »  plus rare.

Elle se trouve au bas de la hiérarchie des formules utilisées pour présenter ses excuses, au dessous d'*excuse-moi* et *pardon*.

On la trouve dans le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/excuser):

> **I.-**, **A.-**, **1.**, **d)**  Par ellipse du complément, familier − *Ma parole, c'est notre curé ! dit-il. **Excusez !** Je ne m'attendais pas à votre visite, je ne pensais pas à vous...* (René Bazin, *Le Blé qui lève*, 1907, p. 234).

On retrouve un peu le même impératif dans la locution ***Excusez du peu !***